# V-text-field autocomplete value doesn't set v-model value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Although my "autocomplete" (Browser Credentials / Saved Username and Password) value appears in the v-text-field when our page is first loaded, it is not equal to my v-model value.

[image: Autocomplete has appear]

For this reason, validations rules return an error and therefore button is disabled.

Then, when I press anywhere or any key, the value fills up and my button becomes enabled.

[image]

And here my code:

```
               <v-text-field
                id="signEmail"
                v-show="!signInPasswordForm"
                class="font-size-base"
                v-model="signInFormProps.signInEmail"
                name="email"
                ref="email"
                type="email"
                :rules="specialEmailRules"
                solo
                flat
                tabindex="1"
              ></v-text-field>
```

What is causing this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a similar problem to what's outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544544/vue-js-v-autocomplete-does-not-update-dynamically-changed-items-correctly/58409934). Try adding the "no-filter" attribute

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe you can work around this problem by triggering some kind of event on the page automatically. For instance, maybe if you "focus" the input after the init, the value for the v-model may subsequently update.

That may be good UX anyway for the the input to be focused by default

Comment: Let me know if that works then I'll update my reply accordingly